# React-native init issue for new app

Tags: react-native

I have been going through the react-native tutorial and ran

react-native init AwesomeApp as detailed in the FB page.

After many trials and errors in setting the correct permissions and path I was able to get the app running on IOS.

Awesome app is in a directory Projects

Now I want to create my own app in the same Projects folder and when I try

react-native init newApp I get

```
 Looks like React Native project already exists in the current
 folder. Run this command from a different folder or remove          node_modules/react-native
```

I tried from a different folder and still get the same message.

What's the best way to resolve this, deleting the node_modules/react-native or is there another solution and why the same error in a different folder?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, the solution wasn't obvious and I find it nowhere on the Internet so I'm leaving it here.

You may have installed `react-native` globally. While you should install `react-native-cli` globally.

Having the first one installed makes typical react-native commads work (starting an app, linking native modules). The only difference is that `init` fails with above message. And IIRC calling `react-native` without arguments reveals the source of the problem with descriptive message that you've globally installed wrong package.

Edit:
On Windows also make sure to use CMD, not PowerShell. PowerShell was calling `react-native` binary (instead of `react-native-cli`) from SOMEWHERE (I don't know the source, I don't have it available globally, I removed every single globally installed package and it was still calling it (probably from some locally insalled copy)).
React Native development caused another issues too (can't remember the details, sorry) when used with Powershell, so just stick to CMD on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably still in the AwesomeApp directory while running `react-native init newApp`.

Try `cd ..` back to the Projects directory and run `react-native init newApp` again.

You will then see newApp directory is created inside the Projects directory.

Comment: I had tried cd .. back to Projects. What I did, was open a new terminal window and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when it is in a folder that you deleted. Try to cd to another folder, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory `C:\\Users\YourUserName` you have a file "nodemodules" and a file named "MyProjectName" .

you should delete nodemodules file.

it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too, Make sure your folder does not have any node modules, if problem persists then install react-native-cli again globally using 
`yarn add global react-native-cli` and then initialize your project.
using `react-native init {name}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because in some parent directory was backuped "node_modules" directory.
Error resolved by rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for everyone this problem gonna be solved by became sudo user in your Mac if you're using macbook now. Then start to create your project one more time.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot parse this answer in this phrasing. In fact, I get the impression that you are not answering at all and are instead trying to say thanks for an existing answer.

Comment: allright here how I Solved the error while create the new project on react native
1. First after I found the error message, I became a root
2. Second, Type react-native init newApp 
3. Third, you have to give back the owner of the directory not as root 
     chown -R abraham newApp
4. Finally, Start Your Project by type npm start in your directory

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the post to make more obvious that you are trying to answer according to [answer]. Maybe also using the info from https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help